# Python error when calling Fourier transform code

Tags: python, numpy

I have some difficulty in running the code. When I run it, this kind of error always appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zhangjq058\workspace\22222222\src\222.py", line 20, in <module>
    x, y = meshgrid(fftfreq(th.shape[0], dx), fftfreq(th.shape[1], dx))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\helper.py", line 153, in fftfreq
    assert isinstance(n,types.IntType) or isinstance(n, integer)
AssertionError
```

**The code is:**

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
N = 100 #lattice points per axis
dt = 1 #time step
dx = 1 #lattice spacing
t = arange(0, 10000*dt, dt) #time
a = 1 #cofficient
epsilon = 100 #cofficient
M = 1.0 #cofficient
every = 100 #dump an image every
phi_0 = 0.5 #initial mean value of the order parameter
noise = 0.1 #initial amplitude of thermal fluctuations in the order parameter
th = phi_0*ones((N, N)) + noise*(rand(N, N) - 0.5) #initial condition
x, y = meshgrid(fftfreq(th.shape[0], dx), fftfreq(th.shape[1], dx))
k2 = (x*x + y*y) #k is a victor in the Fourier space, k2=x^2+y^2
g = lambda th, a: 4*a*th*(1-th)*(1-2*th) #function g
def update(th, dt, a, k2): 
    return ifft2((fft2(th)-dt*M*k2*fft2(g(th,a)))/(1+2*epsilon*M*dt*k2**2))

for i in range(size(t)):
    print t[i]
    if mod(i, every)==0:
        imshow(abs(th), vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
        colorbar()
        savefig('t'+str(i/every).zfill(3)+'.png', dpi=100)
        clf()
th=update(th, dt, a, k2)
```

Comment: Please edit this post, and re-post the code, selecting it and clicking the **`{}`** (code format) button, instead of double-spacing every line.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Neither can I on Python 2.7.6, Fedora 19; can you share your setup?

Comment: Hey, mine's Python 2.7. But I use PyDev (Python IDE). I think probably there is something wrong with the IDE.

Comment: By the way, did you both run the code successfully? Is there any other problem? Thank you!

Comment: I cant reproduce the bug either. What version of numpy do you have?

Comment: numpy-MKL-1.6.1. Could you run the code successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are under Windows 64-bit i assume. There is a bug in your numpy version, where
windows Long type is not recognized as int. Either update numpy or cast your shapes 
manually:

```
fftfreq(int(th.shape[0]), dx)
```

Comment: You are right! I modified the code according to your advice. It works! :>. But one is that the code aims at demonstrating the change of th (composition) in 2D real space with time. why couldn't I see the figure while I was running it? Thank you!